# Sign up with no price

Tags: 7, ubercart

What we need is essentially a free product order. We need viewers to be able to sign up for free classes where there is a limit on the number of students. The registration requirement and the inventory limit indicate that it should be a shopping cart function, but the module that allows for free orders is only available in a Drupal 6 module. Is there such a function for Drupal 7?

Answer (score 1):

Ubercart for D7 has a built in [free order payment method](http://api.ubercart.me/api/drupal/ubercart!payment!uc_payment!uc_payment.module/function/uc_payment_method_free_order/7) so the UC Free Order module isn't needed here. You can configure the conditions under which the payment method is available under the payment method configuration page (**Store > Configuration > Payment method**).

If you need to limit available purchases, the included UC stock module enables restricting products to a limited quantity of available purchases.

Comment: This answer was very helpful, but it feels disconnected to my assumption that the condition of "free" would be attached to the specific art classes in question. That assumption is based on my client's situation where specific classes are free to all comers within the class size available, as opposed to meeting some conditions of buying other products. With the method you describe, can free be attached to a class type product?

Comment: The way the questions is titled/worded made it sound like it was only concerned with free products. I added a line about the UC stock module. That should enable limited purchases that you need for registration.

Comment: It looks like I've been unclear yet again. The question is can a product, in the form of a class, be set to be free for all members or non-members. I have the Free Order Payment Method set, but that is a "free order." What I really need is a "free product." Or, maybe this is as simple as leaving the price at 0?